# How to not allow to insert a new record if count of current records exceeds a specified limit

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, limits

I have two tables as the following

`team`

```
`id` BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`member_limit` INT NOT NULL
```

`team_member`

```
`id` BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`team_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
`member_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT `fk_team_member_team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_team_member_member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
```

My question is on MySQL

How to not allow to insert a new member into `team_member` when the inserted member's `team_id` reference to team that count of its current members on `team_member` exceeds its `member_limit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_check_limit
BEFORE INSERT
ON team_member
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM team_member
         WHERE team_id = NEW.team_id ) > ( SELECT member_limit - 1
                                           FROM team
                                           WHERE id = NEW.team_id ) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Team limit reached!';
    END IF;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ebbecb720cb93c04bb7b83b98e5c16a) with some explanations.

Comment: As designed, this trigger does not prevent an UPDATE that reassigns a team
member. Granted it was not in the original description, but it would
be a requirement.

Comment: @JimD *this trigger does not prevent an UPDATE that reassigns a team member* That is true. And this is done in strict accordance with the task set by the author: "How to **not allow to insert** a new member into team_member **when** the inserted member's team_id reference to team that **count** of its current members on team_member **exceeds its member_limit**". No words about UPDATE. Nevertheless it is enough to alter one word (and trigger name) and double the code (check both OLD and NEW teams) - and update check is realized too.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your answer however I have a quick question: lets say there's a team with `id`: `1` and `member_limit`:`1` now if the following two queries executed at the same time `INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 600);`, `INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 700);`.
did the trigger will also executed at the same time so I'll have members out of the `member_limit` range.

Comment: @AmjedOmar In theory it is possible that the number of players will be over-limited in such case under default server settings. This depends on current transaction level settings (each query is separate transaction).

Answer (score 2):

This should be achievable with a simple query.  We'll have to query `team` and `team_member` to get the required information, so might as well do everything at once:

```
INSERT INTO team_member
SELECT
  team.team_id
 ,<the user's id>
FROM
  team team
INNER JOIN
  team_member team_member
    ON team_member.team_id = team.id
WHERE
  team.id = <team id>
GROUP BY
  team.team_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) < team.member_limit
```

When you wrap this in a stored procedure you can raise a flag if `ROW_COUNT() = 0`.

A couple of other notes:

1. The `Id` column of `team_member` is unnecessary, does not guarantee uniqueness for the intended purpose.  Your primary key is `(team_id,member_id)`.
2. As a naming convention, just using `Id` is poor form.  Always use the context so the relation is clear, e.g. `User_Id`, `Team_Id`.

Answer (score -1):

Cross row constraints are tricky and the implementation depends on the API you present.  You may be able to adapt this technique https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:4233459000346171405 from AskTOM.

As recommended in the comments, here is a solution that works but has its limitations.  When dealing with cross row constraints, my recommendation is to carefully evaluate any solution with a complete set of requirements.  The question, as posted, only mentioned the INSERT limitation; however, not acting on UPDATEs and DELETEs would cause problems.

I opted for an AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE because I generally prefer to modify related tables in an AFTER trigger.  That may not be the right solution for your specific use case, so *caveat emptor*.

The lack of deferrable constraint checking in MySQL makes this type of cross row constraint difficult to make robust.  Assuming MySQL is a hard requirement, the assignment of users to teams should probably be managed by stored procedures.

```
CREATE TABLE team (
  `id`            BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `name`          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `member_count`  INT, 
  `member_limit`  INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  `id`            BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE team_member (
  `id` BIGINT   PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id`     BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `member_id`   BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_team_member_team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
    REFERENCES `team` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_team_member_member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE team
  ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_team_member_limit
    CHECK ((member_count >= 0) AND (member_count <= member_limit))
;
    
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_ai_update_team_size
AFTER INSERT
ON team_member
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE team SET member_count = NVL(member_count,0) + 1
      WHERE id=NEW.team_id;
END;
//
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_au_update_time_size
AFTER UPDATE
ON team_member
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE team SET member_count = NVL(member_count,0) + 1
      WHERE id=NEW.team_id;
    UPDATE team SET member_count = NVL(member_count,0) - 1
      WHERE id=OLD.team_id;
END;
//
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_ad_update_team_size
AFTER DELETE
ON team_member
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE team SET member_count = NVL(member_count,0) - 1
      WHERE id=OLD.team_id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Some test statements

```
INSERT INTO team VALUES (1, 'Team 1', null, 3);
INSERT INTO team VALUES (2, 'Team 2', null, 2);

INSERT INTO user VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (4);

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (3, 1, 3);

INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (4, 1, 4);

DELETE FROM team_member where team_id=1 and member_id=3;
INSERT INTO team_member VALUES (4, 1, 4);
```

[Here is a mockup on dbfiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eba4faa4dba3b545840112278547e41f)

Pros:

- Avoids having a SELECT clause in the trigger (avoiding a full index
  scan or *shudder* full table scan plus the attendant concerns about
  transaction isolation)
- The check constraint enforces the limitation in the team table, thus
  preventing buffoonery
- The member_count column could make some routine queries more efficient
  (e.g. how many people are on a team).

Cons:

- An update statement that swaps users between teams that are full will
  fail because MySQL does not support deferrable constraints.
- The introduction of the member_count column.

I am not a big fan of having columns that are essentially derived from something else stored in the database, but I will make the trade-off for performance or constraint checking reasons.  I tend to advocate for constraints because, in my experience, making the database enforce data quality prevents buffoonery by applications or users.